# <Today_date>T00:00:00.000+0000 is not returned when TODAY is used in Where clause

Tags: node.js, soql, jsforce

I am inserting record with scan_date as **<Today_date>T00:00:00.000+0000**, but I am not able retrieve the same using scan_date = TODAY *(SOQL)*.

example:

There is record with **scan_date = "2022-01-10T00:00:00.000+0000"**, but the record is empty when I queried

```
SELECT Id  FROM <Table_name> where Scan_Date__c=TODAY
```

But I am retrieve the same data by using query

```
SELECT Id  FROM <Table_name> where Scan_Date__c=YESTERDAY
```

BTW I am using **JsForce** with **nodeJS**.

Answer (score 0):

**I solved using DAY_ONLY()**

I used the DAY_ONLY() with Scan_Date__c to just compare the date and ignore the time.

```
SELECT Id  FROM <Table_name> where DAY_ONLY(Scan_Date__c)=TODAY
```

**Reference**

1. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_date_functions.htm#